# How can I stop Excel displaying a different file after printing?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Let say I have 2 excel files opened.

I go to the first file, open the Print page setup, click OK for printing and then, after the page setup is closed, Excel displays the other file and not the one I just printed.

Is there any setting in Excel that will force it to stay with the file I just printed?

Comment: And then make the second print or just swap to the other xls file?

Comment: no, I want just to remain to the window which contains the excel file that was sent to printer. But it displays the other window with the other file which is opened, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a problem with how Office works with documents. It switches to the last opened when it gets focus, not the sheet you work in, because all sheets are stored in one window.

I know a workaround by opening a second instance of excel by shift-clicking excel in the taskbar (windows 7 and up). Opening the other excelfile in that instance will not cause you to swap to that instance when printing the first. And this way, you can also easily put excel in 2 displays or side by side using <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>arrow left</kbd> and <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>arrow right</kbd>

Comment: I go with two instances as well.  Side by side is handy, though if you are manipulating data between the sheets you do lose some functionality.

Comment: @LPChip thanks for your response. I'm talking about two different files, not a single file with different sheets.

Comment: So am I. Excel's MDI interface is the problem. By using 2 instances of Excel, the problem goes away.